# List query returns wrong links for items (AAM misconfiguration?)

Tags: web-part, query, alternate-access-mapping

I have a webpart that sends a query to a list and returns items as links. For some users, not all mind you, the link goes to a different hostname which appears to be set up with AAM. To make matters worse, this behavior isn't consistant, and I am unable to recreate it with my own user. With regards to the inconsistency; I will explain below. The web application is not extended, but AAM is set up in Central Administration and binding are active in the IIS manager. The web part in question works exactly as it should on other environments, but I struggle with this one. Since it works elsewhere, AAM setups included, I have come to believe that there must be something wrong with the AAM configuration.

The problem can be described as follows:

- User is connected internally to the network, and is using SharePoint through internal adressing to http://company
- User enters query string in webpart and is able to click on a link
  once presented
- The user should be sent to http://company/projects/#number#/Finance/Forms/Allitems.aspx, but is instead directed to EITHER https://subcompany.company.something.com/projects/#number#/Finance/Forms/Allitems.aspx or https://company.something.com/projects/#number#/Finance/Forms/Allitems.aspx. When directed to those the user gets a 404 error.
- If the user tries again, by clicking the back button in the browser, enters the query again and clicks the link, they are forwarded to the correct address http://company/projects/#number#/Finance/Forms/Allitems.aspx
- My own user never experiences this, and is always directed to the right address. This is a farm administrator user if that matters.

AAM is configured like this:

Internal URL = I  |   Zone = Z   | Public URL for Zone = PZ

I: http://company, Z: Default, PZ: http://company

I: https://company.something.com, Z: Internet, PZ: https://company.something.com

I: https://subcompany.company.something.com, Z: Custom, PZ: https://subcompany.company.something.com

IIS is configured like this:

Type = T | Host name = H | Port = P | IP Address = IP

T: http, H: company, P: 80, IP: 192.168.4.6

T: https, H: #BLANK#, P: 443, IP: 192.168.4.6

T: http*, H: subcompany.company.something.com, P: 80, IP: 192.168.4.6

T: http*, H: company.something.com, P: 80, IP: 192.168.4.6

(* shouldn't these be https? - they are in fact set up as http)

I rarely configure the AAM or IIS bindings my self, but I have been asked to look into this. The environment itself is in constant use, so I am unable to experiment as much as I'd like without impacting the users. I turn to your expertise. Has anyone seen anything like this before, or have any idea of why this is occurring? I'm not married to the AAM hypothesis, could it be the search service?

Comment: "I have a webpart that sends a query to a list and returns items as links." What type of query are you running? Have you set up something in Search Administration inside SharePoint CA?